# How to detect wrong function call to a typescript function, from a js file [TypeScript, Vue, js]

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js, vuejs2

I have a vue2 app, and I want to start using TypeScript for some services files (without changing existing js/vue files).

In order to add TypeScript support I've used vue-cli, and it seems to work: I've added a myService.ts file with a TypeScript function - myFunction, and inside this file vue detects properly types issues. I can also import this service to a vue component file -  myComponent.vue (a component that contains js code), and use it properly.

myFunction looks like this:

```
function myFunction (x: number, y: number) : number {
  const a: number = 3
  const b: number = 2
  return a + b + x + y
}
```

However, when I call myFunction from myComponent.vue with wrong parameters, for example - `myFunction("str1", "str2")`, **vue doesn't detect any issue, even though string parameters should not be allowed**.
I can run - npm run serve, and it works without raising any warning/error.

**How can I make vue to detect it? is it even possible to detect TS issues from inside js code?**

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible to type check js files but first you need to set up your tsconfig correctly.
[All available options for tsconfig](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig)

What you need:
[allowJs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#allowJs)
[checkJs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#checkJs)

You can also add `// @ts-check` at the top of every js file you want to type check, instead of enabling this option for the whole project.

***EDIT:***
I've read your latests comment, with that in mind, there's a nice guide on TS docs about [slowly migrating from JS](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/migrating-from-javascript.html).

I'm also adding here two codesandboxes, [one](https://codesandbox.io/s/frosty-wildflower-8jdnlx?file=/src/app.js) is built with a TS function that's being used in JS with @ts-check and @ts-ignores.
The [second](https://codesandbox.io/s/fast-http-gk3ujm?file=/src/app.js) is built with JsDoc, you can see it is not being checked without @ts-check enabled also, but I've read that it is possible to enable JsDoc typechecking if you add `"javascript.implicitProjectConfig.checkJs": true` to your vscode settings, I can not confirm though as I have never used JsDoc.

I'm afraid there are not many options other than migrating the files you need to TS and setting correct types (or at least setting everything to type any just to calm TS down), or enabling @ts-check and adding @ts-ignore before every line that you don't want to be checked.

Comment: thanks for your reply! as far as I understand, using allowJs and checkJs, or using // @ts-check, will check all the js code in the file, as if it's all TS. however, I want only this specific function call to be checked (because this is the only TS function in the code). is it possible?

Comment: @RazLib The best way to achieve this would be moving the function call into a separate file if possible and enabling ts-check. You could also leave ts-check on for the whole file and add ts-ignore before lines of code that you’re not interested in checking or explicitly saying every thing else is of type any as you’re migrating to TS, but that’s a very redundant workaround. JsDoc could be another solution, yet considering the fact that I have no experience with it, I cannot point out it’s pros and cons. May I ask why you’re not interested in typechecking everything?

Comment: the reason I don't want to type-checking everything is that we haven't migrated the whole app to TS yet, and I'm not even sure we will do it. I just want to let the developers to be able to write some new files with TS, and call these new TS functions from the existing js files. is that makes sense?

Comment: @RazLib Mentioning so you get a notification. I have edited my answer instead of writing a new one.